# Why is Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase owned by root?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, root

I know it might not be very relevant, but I wanted to know if there is a reason the /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase directory has these permissions

[image: permissions]

Why is read & write only for root?

The `ll` command outputs:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 abr 26  2018 Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase/
```

Is there something to learn from this security-wise?

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output. In addition, you should include *full path* to the directory you're asking about.

Comment: If I try to post the images I get an alert message that reads: "you're not allowed to embed images in your post yet, so we've included a link instead.  as soons as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you'll be able to embed images."

Comment: Don't include pictures of text. Include *text*, not images of text. And add full path to the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite obvious. These permissions are set this way because Ubuntu maintainers have set them this way.

The permissions don't stop normal users from playing media files, because everyone can access the files.

Also a user having `sudo` permissions has full access to that directory.

The reason for setting the permissions is that the directory is provided by `example-content` package.

You can find this out by running

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase
```

Generally it is strongly not recommended to modify or remove files provided by a deb package.

You can remove the package by

```
sudo apt remove example-content
```

if you don't need it.